# php mysql error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE SET numb='61' WHERE
> ID='#ID'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_2.1\php\send.php:20 Stack
> trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web_2.1\php\send.php(20):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE depo...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\web_2.1\php\send.php on line 20

I trying to add numbers in mysql database, for example:

```
session_start();

include('info.php');

$add = $_POST['submit'];

$ID=$_SESSION['ID'];

$query="SELECT numb FROM `prof` WHERE ID='$ID'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$pr=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($pr>0){

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $i=$row['numb'];
    $total = $i + $add;


$querys="UPDATE `prof` WHERE SET numb='$total' WHERE ID='$ID'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $querys);

    header("Location: send.php");

} else{

    $sql="INSERT INTO `prof` (ID, numb)VALUES($ID, $add)";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: /web_2.1/profile.php");
}
```

but after sending first query I can't send second one and getting this error

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, no, no.  Where is your SQL query?   It has a syntax issue.  Right after defining the query. Assuming your query is stored in $sql: Add an echo $sql;  Then copy the SQL into phpMyAdmin (or similar)  and run the query.  Keep trying until there is no error.  No one here can help you with the amount of information you provided.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Really?  `WHERE SET numb='61' WHERE ID='#ID''` and that's what you come up with?  Maybe he needs a third WHERE.

Comment: Hahahah @Misunderstood I completely missed that :)

Answer (score -2):

Try with below query string

```php
$querys = "UPDATE `prof` SET numb='$total' WHERE ID='$ID'";
```

Comment: still the same error

Comment: you can't possibly get the same `near WHERE SET` error with `WHERE SET` no longer being there

Answer (score -3):

This query has two WHERE keywords, that is not valid SQL, there can only be one WHERE:

```
$querys="UPDATE prof WHERE SET numb='$total' WHERE ID='$ID'";
```

What you are looking for seems to be an AND condition, replacing the 2nd WHERE with an AND keyword instead:

```
$querys="UPDATE prof WHERE SET numb='$total' AND ID='$ID'";
```

Comment: No, still the same error

Comment: if in the database empty row, code is working, but after setting number I can't set the second

Comment: stupid me, missed the SET after the first WHERE, so the corrected query would remove the first WHERE:

 `$querys="UPDATE prof SET numb='$total' WHERE ID='$ID'";`

"if in the database empty row, code is working"

That's because the `if($pr>0)` branch that has the bad query is only taken when having found rows, otherwise you get to the `else` branch that does not have that query.